# flikr api+iphone+for geting photos and latitude/longitude of that photos

Tags: iphone

I want to use the flikr api. 
in which i can pass current latitude -longitude and can get the photos and latitude and longitude of that photos.

Please help me..If flikr is providing any such url then..
And also please help me if anyone had any knowledge of other such kind of api

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a good example/tutorial in below link of Flicker API integration. Also you can get [Flicker API here](https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr) for Objective C.

1. http://iosdevelopertips.com/networking/iphone-json-flickr-tutorial-part-1.html

Comment: thanks for the reply and link.But i already have it..but in this example i m getting only photos and not the latitude & longitude of that photo